# Update Python Libraries directly on SD Card

Tags: python, sd-card, update

I do not have an internet connection at my house, I can however connect to the internet where I work. Is it possible to install and update python libraries directly from my mac onto my SD card.

Comment: do you mean `pip` modules or `apt` packages?

Comment: Possible Duplicate for [Raspberrypi SE Query](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8644/how-do-i-download-the-python-libraries-without-a-direct-internet-connection-on-m)

Comment: I mean atp packages

Comment: You can install the packages offline but not sure update is possible

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: Do you want to install complete python or do you already have it and just need other related libraries? My best guess is just take your pi to work and connect it to the internet. It will be extremely difficult in your case to put those apt packages since on package may have more than a couple dependencies. Try looking at the link mentioned in the above comment if you can get something

Comment: I just want the related libraries. I guess ill give up on that and just bring the pi here

Comment: It is a better option since you never know which dependencies might not be around if you do install them offline

Comment: I figured I could avoid that because i was going to install them directly onto  my pi sd card. Why cant I sudo apt-get without my pi?

Comment: Your SD card will have your operating system on it. If you write on it chances are you will erase the OS and then your pi won't be of any use. Apt packages require data from servers over the internet in order to get your all the packages that you want. If the package is not in your Stock OS it will be at servers around the world or near you to get it to your pi